# update command dropdown control

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
myadp.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@idnasb", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse( dridnasb.SelectedItem.Value.ToString());
myadp.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@iddevice", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(drdevice.SelectedItem.Value.ToString());
```

Why in this update command dropdownlist doesn't update?

Comment: What dropdownlist are you talking about?   Why would it update when you aren't changing it?